# ternary operator vs [collection if].first performance?

Tags: flutter, dart

any performance advantages of using this syntax :

```
ColoredBox(
    color: isValid ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
);
```

instead of this ?

```
ColoredBox(
    color: <Color>[
        if(isValid) Colors.green
        else Colors.red
    ].first,
);
```

the second one is more readable and clean for me , is there any performance disadvantages of using it ?

Edit:

i think the first example does not clarify my idea , this one does .

```
DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(

        borderRadius: (isOpened && isFav)
            ? BorderRadius.circular(30)
            : (isOpened && !isFav && isClicked
                ? BorderRadius.circular(10)
                : BorderRadius.circular(0)),

        borderRadius: <BorderRadius>[
          if(isOpened && isFav)
            BorderRadius.circular(30)
          else if(isOpened && !isFav && !isClicked)
            BorderRadius.circular(10)
          else 
            BorderRadius.circular(0)
        ].first
      ),
    );
```

Edit 2:

i made some quick tests to check which one is faster and these were the results :

test 1 :
ternary operator score : 19ms,
collection if score : 5ms

test 2 :
ternary operator score : 22ms,
collection if score : 7ms

tests source code :

```
import "dart:math";

int ternaryOperatorScore, collectionIfScore;

void main() {
  test1();
  test2();
}

void test1() {
  int tStartTimeInMs = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  int _;
  for (int i = 0; i < pow(10, 5); i++) {
    _ = [if (i.isOdd) 0 else 1].first;
  }
  ternaryOperatorScore = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - tStartTimeInMs;

  int cStartTimeInMs = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  for (int i = 0; i < pow(10, 5); i++) {
    _ = i.isOdd ? 0 : 1;
  }
  collectionIfScore = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - cStartTimeInMs;

  printTestResult(1);
}

void test2() {
  int tStartTimeInMs = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  List<int> _list = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < pow(10, 5); i++) {
    _list.add([if (i.isOdd) 0 else 1].first);
  }
  ternaryOperatorScore = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - tStartTimeInMs;

  int cStartTimeInMs = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  for (int i = 0; i < pow(10, 5); i++) {
    _list.add(i.isOdd ? 0 : 1);
  }
  collectionIfScore = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - cStartTimeInMs;

  printTestResult(2);
}

void printTestResult(n) {
  print(""" test $n :
       ternary operator score : ${ternaryOperatorScore}ms,
       collection if score : ${collectionIfScore}ms \n""");
}
```

Comment: Lol, to keep the code cleaner of course. Also, it's easier to read the first one than the second

Comment: i edited the example to clarify my idea @RandalSchwartz

Comment: Eeek.  Far more complicated.  I'd work it out as a method returning the value, with multiple return exit points.  And those magic 30, 10, 0 constants really should also be refactored to give them meaning.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz yeah i agree it should be refactored but that was just a demonstration i am not using it on my code , btw i am not asking about the syntax if its complicated or not i am asking if its less performant or so , any idea?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz sorry it was my fault to not clarify , what i meant is : will be there any PERFORMANCE disadvantages of using this second syntax instead of the first one?

Comment: I would expect that creating an unnecessary `List` and dereferencing its only element would be more wasteful (and therefore use a bit more battery power) than not.  Unless you're doing it a lot, though, it probably wouldn't be noticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance difference between the two options is so low that you can just pick one and go with it. To do an example, You could probably notice some MS difference if you run one billion ternary/if-else (in that case probably the ternary might be faster - of 0.0001 ms and probably even way less than that).
As far as I am aware, this is the same in a lot of languages.
Pick the one that is more readable for everybody.

And from your example, it looks like the first example is way more clear/easier to read for everybody.